# Tika parser python with Docker giving RuntimeError: Details: Unable to start Tika server

Tags: python, docker, apache-tika, tika-server

**Without Docker the scripts are able to parse the pdf files using tika.**

But however when I'm trying with Docker..I get the following error for the tika server not running: with some reading I tried the following - but the error persists.

Can some please help?

I'm attaching the Dockerfile in the end and listing the docker containers that are running -

1. docker pull apache/tika
2. docker run -d -p 9998:9998 apache/tika
3. cat Dockerfile (listing in the end)
4. docker build -t docker_parser .
5. docker run docker_parser
6. docker ps -a

```
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                    NAMES

    8ff9fd3d0a84        docker_parser       "python ./scripts/..."   2 days ago          Exited (0) 4 minutes ago                            adoring_mestorf

    fdf132926c61        apache/tika         "/bin/sh -c 'java ..."   2 days ago          Up 6 minutes               0.0.0.0:9998->9998/tcp   optimistic_ride
```

7. Dockerfile:

```
    FROM python:3

    RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip requests
    RUN pip3 install python-docx tika numpy pandas

    RUN mkdir scripts
    RUN mkdir pdfs
    RUN mkdir output

    ADD runner.py /scripts/
    ADD header_parser.py /scripts/
    ADD keyword_parser.py /scripts/

    ADD *.pdf /pdfs/

    CMD [ "python", "./scripts/runner.py" ]
```

**8. Error in the code:
 sentence_parser Oops!  Error Type:   occured. Details:  Unable to start Tika server.  Error Type:   at line: 156**

Comment: The Apache Tika Server is written in Java, do you have that in your docker image too? (Looks not...)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't specified a link between the containers, so tika-python isn't able to connect to port 9998. You could add Java in the docker_parser container and let it host Tika Server, otherwise you'll need to link the containers.

If you want to use the two images, you can either use the --link option on Docker CLI at run time, or build a network (*docker network create*) and attach the two containers together (*docker network connect*). I normally use *docker-compose* to make these kind of things easier and specify the links there.